# How to control maximum concurrent clients on spring boot Oauth2

Tags: spring-boot, concurrency, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have a rest API spring boot application with oAuth2 security. there are no restrictions on registering clients and **I need to specify the maximum concurrent number of tokens allowed**. I couldn't find any Oauth2 configuration. What is the best solution to do that?

Grant_type is **client_credentials** and I am using a Jdbc TokenStore

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: The question is not  clear. You wan to restrict number of active session for a user?

Comment: sorry for being late. yes I wanna restrict the number of active sessions per user and the total number of sessions for all users